# float doesn't return in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

Why float doesn't return the wanted value in another activity. All the other ints, and Strings does, but float doesn't.

Sender activity:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                        "details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                edit.putInt("weight", weight);
                edit.putInt("height", height);
                edit.putInt("age", ag);
                edit.commit();

Log.d("BMI Height" , String.valueOf(height));
Log.d("BMI Weight" , String.valueOf(weight));
```

> BMI Height and weight in the console are the correct

Receiver activity:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
            "details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int age=prefs.getInt("age", Integer.parseInt("16"));
    int weight=prefs.getInt("weight", Integer.parseInt("50"));
    int height=prefs.getInt("height", Integer.parseInt("165"));

Log.d("BMI Height" , String.valueOf(height));
Log.d("BMI Weight" , String.valueOf(weight));

    float formula = weight / (height * height) * 10000;

    Log.d("BMI Formula", String.valueOf(formula));
```

> BMI Height and weight in the console are the still correct, but formula returns 0.0 in the console.

Comment: you have put int value in sharedpreferences you have put double

Comment: where do i have to put double

Comment: If all your values are int Java makes an devision by int value: try (float)weight / (height * height) * 10000;

Comment: Try this:
float formula = (float) weight / (height * height) * 10000;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're doing math on integers and storing the result in a float.  The math is still done on integers.  So you'll divide weight (50) by height*height (around 10K).  THat's less than 1, but the result of dividing two integers is always an integer.  So it rounds to 0.

To fix that, make weight and height floats.

Comment: But if I wanted to loop this like after sending the notification/doing the action it counts the same time and does same thing after the estimated time. Example. "5mins - <action> - 5mins - <action>..."

Comment: And the same keeps repeating till the app is deleted or the time is changed

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
edit.putFloat("key", (float) 10.10);
```

and try to get the value

```
prefs.getFloat("key", (float) 10.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

since weight and height are integers so probably the result should be zero.
For example

```
int a = 10
int b = 5

float c = a/(b*b);
```

it will return 0 because calculation in int results 0 and then it will typecast into float 0.0
you can typecast weight and height to float like

```
float c = (float)a/((float)b*(float)b);
```

then it will return you 0.400

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are dividing ints, the result is then automatically cast to float, So if the result isn't great enough you get 0 (and either way you'd get an int).

You have to cast the first int in the division to float to get the desired result.

```
float formula = (float) weight / (height * height) * 10000;
```